# How to play base64 audio data on firefox with using HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, base64, html5-audio

I'm trying to encode an mp3 file in base64 format. Then play it through the broswer. It works perfectly on safari and chrome, but not on **Firefox**.

My question is **"is there any way that make firefox play an audio file in base64/ binary string format?"**

ps: i know firefox can't play mp3, so i've tried others audio file like wav, ogg... None of them is working on Firefox after I have encoded them to base64. Please help

```
<body>
    <div>
        <form>
        Select a file: <input type="file" name="img" id="myaudio"/>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="click">
        <span>click</span>
    </div>
    <div id="body">
        <audio controls="controls" autobuffer="autobuffer" autoplay="autoplay">
        </audio>

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
              $("#click").click(function(){
                    var audio = $("input[type='file']").get(0).files[0];

                    readFile(audio, function(e) {
                        var result = e.target.result;   *// here I get a binary string of my original audio file*
                        encodedData = btoa(result);   *// encode it to base64*
                        $("audio").html("<source src=\"data:audio/mp3;base64,"+encodedData+"\"/>");     *//add the source to audio*
                    });
              });

        });

        function readFile(file, onLoadCallback){
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = onLoadCallback;
            reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
        }


    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `readAsBinaryString` then base64 encoding.
use `readAsDataURL` which gives you a complete data uri.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#click").click(function(){
                var audio = $("input[type='file']").get(0).files[0];

                readFile(audio, function(e) {
                    var result = e.target.result;   *// here I get a binary string of my original audio file*
                    //encodedData = btoa(result);   *// encode it to base64*
                    $("audio").html("<source src=\""+result+"\"/>");     *//add the source to audio*
                });
          });

    });

    function readFile(file, onLoadCallback){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = onLoadCallback;
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }


</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Z9pJ7/2/

Comment: I am not supposed to do that. The code that I provided above is just test code. What I actually want to do is to get audio data from a db which is already in base64 format when I get it, then play it on browser (Firefox). but thx :)

Comment: And I just tested your suggestion, it still works for Chrome but not Firefox :(

Comment: @Dominic see update I forgot to remove the btoa stuff, I tested this on an ogg file and it worked.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply!!! I move the code from my MAC to PC, then it works! thx! but now I am wondering is there any differences between Firefox on PC and MAC, which might cause my problem? I've checked both Firefox are the same 23.0 version. 

My Mac Firefox gives me error like "HTTP "Content-Type" of "audio/mp3" is not supported. Load of media resource data
:audio/mp3;base64, [base64 string]....
but my PC Firefox works fine.

Thank you so much! Sorry for asking so many questions. Please give me some suggestions of my problems... THX THX THX!!

Comment: @Dominic Because mp3 is patent encumbered, Firefox does not support mp3 playback **unless** it can use an OS-level module for mp3 playback. Firefox can currently use the mp3 module in Windows, but (apparently) not in Mac OS.

Comment: @apsillers Would you have any chance to know how i can get around that in order to play base64 mp3 binary string on Firefox browser on MAC?? (the data that i got from db is in base 64 format) Any hints or possible suggestion would be good, cause I have a project due tmr. really really appreciate to your comment!!!